# iATS payment REJECT: 15 response code

Tags: iats

I am using Drupal 8 with CiviCRM and added iATS for donation.
Contribution page is returing REJECT:15 number code.
I searched on iATS site to meaning of this reject code and found that it is

REJ:15
General decline code. Please have client call the number on the back of credit card https://content.iatspayments.com/developers-credit-card-reject-codes-north-america

is anybody know the solution for this problem?
[image]

Log message

```
$iATS SOAP Response = stdClass Object ( 
[ProcessCreditCardWithCustomerCodeResult] => stdClass Object ( [any] => <IATSRESPONSE xmlns=""><STATUS>Success</STATUS><ERRORS/><PROCESSRESULT><AUTHORIZATIONRESULT> REJECT: 15 </AUTHORIZATIONRESULT><CUSTOMERCODE>A30312979</CUSTOMERCODE><SETTLEMENTBATCHDATE> 10/10/2021 </SETTLEMENTBATCHDATE><SETTLEMENTDATE> 10/11/2021 </SETTLEMENTDATE><TRANSACTIONID>ADC2D7AC </TRANSACTIONID></PROCESSRESULT></IATSRESPONSE> ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for REJ:15 using iATS test accounts.

Here is the list of amounts and the response if you use test visa 41/

```
1.00 OK: 678594;
2.00 REJ: 15;
3.00 OK: 678594;
4.00 REJ: 15;
5.00 REJ: 15;
6.00 OK: 678594:X;
7.00 OK: 678594:y;
8.00 OK: 678594:A;
9.00 OK: 678594:Z;
10.00 OK: 678594:N;
15.00, if CVV2=1234 OK: 678594:Y; if there is no CVV2: REJ: 19
16.00 REJ: 2;
Other Amount REJ: 15
```

If you use test visa 42/ then you can process any amount between $1 and $2000

REf: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/blob/master/README.md

Comment: That’s not entirely correct -> iATS TEST agent codes can process any anount between $1 and $2000 depending on the CardNumber. 41/ does what you describe above. 42/ does not.

Comment: I’ve made the above clear in the answer 

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Thanks for your update on 42/ CC details. I just verified and its works. I can process large amount with 42/ CC details. Thank you